# Google Workspace Addon incompatibility between different Workspace instances?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I am developing a small Google Workspace Add on for a customer.

The way I am doing this is by developing it on a different Google Workspace and after testing, I copy it to the customer Google Workspace. However I encounter that there are some differences between those Google Workspaces because I got an error on the customer Workspace when using the Add on. The following piece of code worked on my Google Workspace:

```
 if(e.commonEventObject.formInputs && e.commonEventObject.formInputs.input){
     userSpeficiedIdentifier = e.commonEventObject.formInputs.input.stringInputs.value[0];
  }
```

However I received the following error on the customers Workspace:

```
TypeError: Can not read "value" of undefined.
```

I was able to fix it on the customer side by adding `[""]` after input like this:

```
 if(e.commonEventObject.formInputs && e.commonEventObject.formInputs.input){
     userSpeficiedIdentifier = e.commonEventObject.formInputs.input[""].stringInputs.value[0];
  }
```

But this leaves me with some questions I can not answer:

1. What exactly is the difference between the customer and my Google Workspace?
2. How can I check before hand if such different in version exist and if there any compatibility issues?

Comment: Are both projects using the same version of Apps Script (Rhino/V8)?

Comment: I disabled V8 for both projects

Comment: Under what context does the line get executed?

Comment: Under the user context who just clicked a button on the Google Workspace Addon which executes a function where this peace of code is in.